# How do you convert datetime into just date using SQL?

Tags: sql, excel

I'm running Excel 2010, and I tried converting my code in sql

`` SELECT Repository$`.`Date Archived` ``

to just read the date without the time stamp, because right now it is seen as a **mm/dd/yyyy/ hh:mm:ss** format

my attempt to the code was using

`` SELECT CAST(Repository$`.`Date Archived) as Date `` 
and an error keeps running saying:

*Undefined function 'CONVERT' in expression*

Anything will help! Thanks

Comment: `CAST(Repository$.Date Archived as Date)`... Parenthesis is in the wrong spot.

Comment: What database server? SQL Server, Oracle. Postgres?

Comment: Using Excel, connecting to a SQL Server